# How can I display reports for specific person?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have 2 models Report and Person with report belongs_to person and report has_many reports.
I want to make a link in People's Grid 'see reports' to display that specific person's reports

{link_to "Reports", admin_reports_path(:person_id => person.id, :date => Date.today)}

However, when clicking this link it shows all the reports from all the people and not only from today.
What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Reports Controller:

def create_daily

```
person_id = @person.id
reports = params[:reports] || []
date = Date.today

  reports.each do |index, attributes|
  project = Project.find_by_short_name(attributes[:short_name])
  project_id = project.id if project
  date = Date.parse(attributes[:date])

  report = Report.where(:person_id => person_id, :project_id => project_id, :date => date).first_or_initialize
  report.person_id     = person_id
  report.project_id    = project_id
  report.date          = date unless report.date  # Do not overwrite if already existing
  report.day_off       = attributes[:day_off] == 'true'
  report.body          = attributes[:body].to_s.strip
  report.time_estimate = attributes[:time_estimate].to_s.strip
  report.save
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to reports_url }
  format.json { render :json => { :reports => Report.by_reporter(current_user).for_date(date) } }
end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to display reports of a person. jus do this in controller

```
 @person = Person.find(params[:person_id)
 @reports= @person.reports.where(:date => Date.today)
```

Comment: I'm using Active Admin and if I give the path parameter (@reports) it just shows admin/reports.I get person.id and date parameters in url so it is kinda fishy

Comment: can not understand what exactly your requirement is . can you please elababorate